# VSTS Azure Resource Group Deployment Task API Version

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I've recently upgraded my ARM Templates to use the new API Version "2017-05-10"  for the "Microsoft.Resources/deployments" type to take advantage of a new feature.

In doing so, the Azure Resource Group Deployment task in VSTS fails because I believe the API version used by the Azure Resource Group Deployment task is an older version. The Error I receive is:

> [error] Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'rds-poc-1' at line '1' and column '4188' is invalid. The nested deployment has api-version '2017-05-10', which is not supported in api-version '2016-07-01' used to deploy the template. Please use api-version '2017-05-10' or later to deploy the template. Or use an older api-version for the nested deployment in the template.

Can anyone verify and make any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy using powershell (don't forget to update it before), not VSTS build step.

Comment: I actually replaced the Resource Group Deployment Task with a PowerShell Task with the code to initiate a Deployment via a Runbook with a Webhook.